# On Mac OS, how does the "open with..." dialog interact with command line arguments?

Tags: python, macos

I'm creating a basic application for opening CBZ files. I'd like to be able to right click on .cbz files in Finder and open them with the specific app (YACReader does this, for example). I've created a test app to print out the command line arguments that the app receives when used this way, but nothing is passed except the name of the executable.

How do Mac applications read the file they are being passed?

I'm currently using python packed with py2app. If there is a solution that works for the Windows "open with" menu item in File Explorer, that would help as well.